# Lamda expression type not recognized correctly

Tags: python, string, lambda, formatting

I'm trying to get the length of columns for string formatting using the maximum length of each column. I am trying to find this using a lambda expression but the type isn't getting recognized correctly.

```
format_string = "".join(("{%d}" % max(list2d, key=lambda c: len(c[i])) for i in range(list2d[0])))
```

Where `list2d` is of type `List[List[str]]`

I would expect this to make a format string with the max length of each index in `range(list2d[0])` but I get:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: `list2d` is not a list of `int`s, so the result of `max` isn't going to be compatible with `%d`. Either use `%s` instead, or reexamine how you produce the intended value for the format operator.

Comment: ```for i in range(list2d[0])``` try ```for i in range(len(list2d[0]))```